# Identity table design for OpenId/Facebook

Tags: facebook, openid

I plan to make a table to hold the Openid or Facebook identities of users. Users have one-to-many mapping to the Identity table

Identity table

```
identity_id  user_id    type      type_id
1            1          facebook  123456789
2            1          google    456789798
3            2          yahoo     123456789
4            2          aol       231634654
5            1          openid    123456789
6            2          openid    878919819
```

type_id is not necessarily composed of numbers only(its just for example here). Also I am still not sure if Google, Yahoo,etc will be under OpenId. If that is the case then maybe I can define 2 types only, Facebook and OpenId. The reason they are separate is that Facebook doesn't have an OpenId implementation yet.

Is this table enough for storing identities or are there some factors that I haven't taken into account?

Comment: i wouldn't try and fudge two different types of authentication into one table. keep them in seperate tables, then you can left outer join on those tables to see what accounts they have.

Comment: The reason that I kept them in one table is that keeping different types in different tables would result in adding a new table whenever a new type is added.